# Is it possible to retrieve icons of apps installed on mac os programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

```
public func getAllApplications() -> [NSMetadataItem] {
    let fileManager = FileManager()

    guard let applicationsFolderUrl = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) else { return [] }

    let applicationUrls = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: applicationsFolderUrl , includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsPackageDescendants, FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants])

    guard let systemApplicationsFolderUrl = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .systemDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) else { return [] }

    let utilitiesFolderUrl = NSURL.init(string: "\(systemApplicationsFolderUrl.path)/Utilities") as! URL

    guard let utilitiesUrls = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: utilitiesFolderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsPackageDescendants, FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsSubdirectoryDescendants]) else { return [] }

    let urls = applicationUrls + utilitiesUrls

    var applications = [NSMetadataItem]()

    for url in urls {
        print(url.path, fileManager.isExecutableFile(atPath: url.path))
        if fileManager.isExecutableFile(atPath: url.path) {
            guard let mdi = NSMetadataItem(url: url) else { continue }
            applications.append(mdi)
        }
    }

    for app in applications {
        print(app.value(forAttribute: kMDItemDisplayName as String))
    }
    return applications
}
```

I was able to retrieve names of the apps installed using above code and from here I couldn't figure it out how to retrieve icon images. I couldn't find any properties that allows me retrieve icon information or I might be seeing in wrong place.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Once you have URL of an app bundle -> load it as Bundle (bundleWithURL). Bundle has infoDictionary. This infoDictionary has a key "CFBundleIconFile". Once you have icon name just load it through NSImage

Comment: also use resourceValues(forKeys: [.isApplicationKey]) instead of isExecutableFile (i think script can be executable)

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you use a very extreme measure.

Comment: @MarekH I don't think there's a need to manually look up the `CFBundleIconFile`. You can just ask [`NSWorkspace.icon(forFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528158-icon) and it'll do that work for you

Comment: @Alexander Wow, I though it only works for documents. Never thought it works for app packages. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC it even resolves any custom icons the user might have set on the specific file. It’s great.

Comment: @MarekH just make sure to use the shared workspace `NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: yourURL.path)`

Comment: I cleaned this up a bit and wrote it so it returned app names and images https://gist.github.com/zackshapiro/dfd1a496c767b6a0fd924723158add05

Comment: Thank you:) Also I wonder is it possible to know what all meta information can be retrieved besides names & icons @ZackShapiro